# Two circles and their distance

Tags: java, graphics

having quite the trouble with my homework this day. Heres the Exercise text:

> (Two circles and their distance) Write a programthat draws two pilled circles with radius **15** pixels, centered at random location, with a line connecting the two circles. The distance between the two centers is displayed on the line. Whenever you resize the frame, the circles are redisplayed in new **random** locations.

Okay, so the code i have at this moment is:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

 public class Exercise13_29 extends JFrame {

public Exercise13_29() {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Exercise13_29 frame = new Exercise13_29();
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setTitle("Exercise13_29");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

class Circles extends JPanel {

}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
 }
}
```

I know this isn't much at all but I'm really stuck here.
I dont even know if i should use drawOval or if something else is more appropriate. 
I also can't seem to find out what code is used to make the circles appear randomly when the frame is resized.

Please help me out here.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I believe the window is automatically repainted when the window is resized.

Comment: @MRJones Well, the problem is that the program needs to respond to the window being resized with repainting the circles.

Comment: @Khilmarsen From the information you've provided, I can only assume that the response you're referring to is drawing the circles at random locations. If this is correct, then break it down... Since the window is repainted each time the window is resized, that means that `paint` is getting called each time the window is resized, and `paint` ultimately calls your `paintComponent` method. So `paintComponent` would be where you would place your logic for updating the circles' coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of smaller problems that you need to solve first.

1. Getting a random position. [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-with-java/363732#363732)
2. Finding the distance between 2 points. [Calculating the distance between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929773/calculating-the-distance-between-two-points)
3. Drawing circles centered at a point http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawOval(int,%20int,%20int,%20int) should help
4. Drawing a line between 2 points http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawLine(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

After you've solved each of these individually, putting them together shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Thank you, ill do my reading and edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

To relocate on window resize, add an event listener on resize events on the frame.

Comment: paint is going to get called on resize anyway, so this isn't necessary. I believe they added this requirement to make the problem easier, not harder.

Comment: Agreed, didn't notice he was doing it in PaintComponent.