# How to chose a random point at a certain distance to a reference point

Tags: java, math, random

I have point **A** (`pointA = (x1, y1)`) and I need to choose a random point **B** (`pointB = (x2, y2)`) such that the distance between the **A** and **B** is equal to **K**.

Comment: [This answer][1] has what you're looking for.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/929781/4805137

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the distance between two points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929773/calculating-the-distance-between-two-points)

Comment: That's not a duplicate of this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a geometry problem, not a coding/software problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's solve in polar form.

We'll need these doubles `distance`, `x1`, and `y1`.

First, we want the angle in radians:

```
double angle = Math.random()*2*Math.PI;
```

Then we want to get the x and y offsets from our point:

```
double xOff = Math.cos(angle)*distance;
double yOff = Math.sin(angle)*distance;
```

Then we add these to our first point:

```
double x2 = x1 + xOff;
double y2 = y1 + yOff;
```

This will get you a point a certain `distance` away from your first point.

Comment: Why angle = Math.random() * 2 * PI ?

Comment: oh i see. max random is 1. 1 * 2 * 3.14 = 6.28 radians = 360°.