# Find nearest location in an ArrayList from given float values

Tags: java, arraylist

I was wondering how I could get the nearest location from given float values.

I have an ArrayList of Cities which have lat/long. What I would like to do is to find the nearest city from given coordinates.

```
public class City {
       private float lat;
       private float lng;
       //getters & setters
   }

   List < City > cities; // at this point "cities" contains several "city"
   City city;



   city = findNearest(lat, lng);
   private City findNearest(float lat, float lng) {
       for (City c: cities) {}
   }
```

Comment: just calculate the differnce between point X and point Y with [math](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html) and store the smallest one in a variable.

Comment: Use a variable to keep track of which one you think is closest and update it as you go through the loop. For each city, find the distance. If it is closer than the one that you previously thought was closest, assign it to the variable. Also, don't post fragments of code that don't make any sense.

Comment: What's your approach? Finding the distance between 2 geo coordinates is a little trickier than @KevinEsche mentioned, but the simple distance is a good start.

Comment: on top of what @khelwood said, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929773/calculating-the-distance-between-two-points (just in case)

Comment: I guess I am terrible in maths because I don't seem to get it well

Comment: My problem is because there are a combination of two values to determinate which City is the nearest that's what I can't still understand

Comment: Did you try your favourite search engine? I found http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/ among others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to calculate simple deviation:

```
  private City findNearest(float lat, float lng) {
       float minDist = Float.MAX_VALUE;
       City resCity = null;
       for (City c: cities) {
          float dist = Math.pow(c.getLat() - lat, 2) + Math.pow(c.getLng() - lng, 2);
          if (dist < minDist){
            minDist = dist;
            resCity = c;
          }
       }
     return resCity;
   }
```

you could take Math.sqrt from dist, but actually there is no sense.